# Postgres find string starting with specific characters

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have this table, in which the order_name was randomly typed. I want to extract the order code after `437.` for 22 characters in their original format, e.g. `437.8/03-87 22LA190028` (it was wrongly written in the second record).

| id | order_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First order 437.8/03-87 22LA190028 |
| 2 | Second order 437.8-03-87 22LA190028 |
| 3 | First order 437.3/10-87 16NY100013 - Return |
| 4 | Order 21.02.2022 437.8/10-87 16WA239766 |
| 5 | 437.8/10-87 16NY100234 - Paid |
| 6 | First order (437.8/03-87 22LA190028) |
| 7 | Visit 02.02.2023 Order 437.5/10-87 16DC107765 |

I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string you want ALWAYS starts with 437 and has a length of 22 you can use  the following regex statement:

```
437...................
```

I think you can select the result of this in postgres by:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(order_name,#'437...................')
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/ this is a nice tool to play around and to find the correct regex statement

Comment: But how will it be solved when the tring has a length of 23?

Comment: in my solution you just add one more .

Comment: I mean it might have either 22 or 23 characters in it.

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(order_name,'437\.{18,19}') FROM yourtable` or maybe `SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(order_name,'(?=437\.).{22,23}') FROM yourtable`